traer los registros completos de una consulta sql a una tabla html
estoy intentando traer todos los registros de mi consulta sql usando c# asp.net core con paginas Razor, el problema es que no esta trayendo a mi tabla todos los registros,
por ejemplo, usando el mismo script sql, tengo 19 registros y en mi tabla solo muestra 6 registros siempre, no encuentro que es lo que limita la muestra a solo 6 registros.
Es una solucion asp.net core con paginas razor, estoy usando datatable y css para los estilos
este es mi Index.cshmtl:
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RCC";
}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha384-..." crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.0/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>




<div style="text-align: right;">
<h5 style="color: cadetblue;">Bienvenid@@, @Model.Username!</h5>
</div>

<!-- Botón para cerrar sesión -->
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Logout">
    <div style="text-align: right;">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" style="border-radius: 100px;"><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-power-off"></i></button>
    </div>

</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.0/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<style>

    .content-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 100vh; /* Asegura que el contenedor ocupe al menos toda la altura de la ventana */
    }

    .modal-dialog {
        margin: 15% auto; /* Centrar verticalmente */
    }

    body {
        background-image: url('/img/fondo_reporte.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        opacity: 0.9;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
       /* align-items: center;*/
       margin-top: 20px;
        height: 90vh; /* Establecer altura del cuerpo para ocupar toda la ventana */
   /*     max-width: 3500px; /* Ancho máximo deseado */*/
   /*     max-height: 500px; /* Alto máximo deseado */*/
    }

    .container {
        background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Color de fondo */
        border-radius: 10px; /* Radio de los bordes */
        padding: 20px; /* Espaciado interno */
        width: 90%; /* Ancho del recuadro */
        margin: 0 auto; /* Centrar horizontalmente */
    }

    /*.rounded-table {
        border-radius: 10px; /* Ajusta el valor según lo redondeado que desees que sea el borde */
        /*overflow: hidden; /* Esto asegura que los bordes redondeados se muestren correctamente */
      
    /*}*/

    /*.custom-table {*/
        /*background-color: cadetblue; /* Reemplaza "your-color" con el color deseado */
        /*color:white;*/
    /*}*/
</style>



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
           
            <div class="modal-body" style="align-self:center">
                BUSCANDO...ESPERE POR FAVOR
            </div>
         
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



@*<div class="content-wrapper">*@


<div style="margin-top:20px" >


    

    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <h3 class="display-10" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; color: cadetblue;">
            <img src="/img/logo_RCC.png" alt="Icono" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; margin-right: 10px;">REPORTE CREDITICIO
        </h3>
    </div>

    <hr style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"> <!-- Línea separadora -->



     <form method="POST">

   
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese DNI separados por comas" aria-label="DNIs" name="DNIs" style="min-height: 40px;max-height:40px"></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="button-addon2" name="consultar">Consultar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="limpiar">Limpiar</button>
        </div>


       
    </form>

    

    <div class="table-container-rounded" >
        <div style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; max-width: 100%; margin-top: 30px;">
        <table id="myTable2" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>DNI</th>
                @*    <th>Entidades</th> *@               
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Normal</th>
                    <th>CPP</th>
                    <th>Deficiente</th>
                    <th>Dudosa</th>
                    <th>Perdida</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
          @*          <th>Apellido</th>
                    <th>Ape Materno</th>
                    <th>Seg Nombre</th>*@
                    <th>Entidad</th>
                    <th>Castigo</th>
                    <th>Saldo</th>
                    <th>Linea</th>
                   @* <th>Linea Tc</th>
                    <th>Linea Tc Nu</th>
                    <th>Hipotecario</th>
                    <th>Días Mora</th>
                    <th>Micr Saldo</th>
                    <th>Micr Línea</th>
                    <th>Peq Saldo</th>
                    <th>Peq Línea</th>
                    <th>Med Saldo</th>
                    <th>Med Línea</th>*@
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.RCC)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.DNI</td>
                    @*    <td>@item.NRO_EMPRESAS</td>*@
                        <td>@item.FEC_REPORTE</td>
                        <td>@item.NORMAL</td>
                      @*  @{
                            // Convertir el valor de "Normal" a un número eliminando el signo de porcentaje
                            string normalValue = item.NORMAL.Trim('%');
                            // Convertir la cadena a un valor numérico
                            decimal normalPercentage = decimal.Parse(normalValue);
                            // Determinar la clase CSS basada en el valor numérico
                            string cssClass = normalPercentage == 100 ? "text-green" : (normalPercentage > 50 ? "text-amber" : "text-red");
                        }
                        <td class="@cssClass"><strong>@item.NORMAL</strong></td>*@
                        <td>@item.CPP</td>
                        <td>@item.DEFICIENTE</td>
                        <td>@item.DUDOSA</td>
                        <td>@item.PERDIDA</td>
                        <td>@item.PRIMER_NOMBRE</td>
         @*               <td>@item.APELLIDO_PATERNO</td>
                        <td>@item.APELLIDO_MATERNO</td>
                        <td>@item.SEGUNDO_NOMBRE</td>*@
                        <td>@item.ENTIDAD</td>
                        <td>@item.TOTAL_CASTIGO</td>
                        <td>@item.SALDO</td>
                        <td>@item.LINEA</td>
         @*               <td>@item.LINEA_TC</td>
                        <td>@item.LINEA_TC_NU</td>
                        <td>@item.HIPOTECARIO</td>
                        <td>@item.DIAS_MORA</td>
                        <td>@item.MICR_SALDO</td>
                        <td>@item.MICR_LINEA</td>
                        <td>@item.PEQ_SALDO</td>
                        <td>@item.PEQ_LINEA</td>
                        <td>@item.MED_SALDO</td>
                        <td>@item.MED_LINEA</td>*@
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>

    </table>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px;">
        <button id="exportButton"  type="button" class="btn btn-success">Exportar</button>
    </div>

</div>
@*</div>*@


@section Scripts{
    <script>
        // Cuando se haya cargado la página
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Ocultar el modal inicialmente
            $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
        });

        // Cuando se haga clic en el botón Consultar
        $('form').submit(function () {
            // Mostrar el modal
            $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>




    <script>
        // Función de exportación a Excel
        function exportToExcel() {
            const table = document.getElementById('myTable2');
            const visibleRows = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr:not([style*="display: none"])');
            const data = [];

            visibleRows.forEach(row => {
                const rowData = [];
                const cells = row.querySelectorAll('td:not(:nth-child(27))');
                cells.forEach(cell => {
                    rowData.push(cell.innerText);
                });
                data.push(rowData);
            });

            //const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([['NombreCompleto', 'Identificacion', 'Telefono', 'FechaIngreso', 'Area', 'Cargo', 'Jefatura'/*, 'Estado'*/, 'Empresa'], ...data]);
            //const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([['Identificacion', 'NRO_EMPRESAS', 'FEC_REPORTE', 'NORMAL', 'CPP', 'DEFICIENTE', 'DUDOSA', 'PERDIDA', 'ApellidoPaterno', 'ApellidoMaterno', 'PrimerNombre', 'SegundoNombre', 'ENTIDAD', 'TOTAL_CASTIGO', 'SALDO', 'LINEA', 'LINEA_TC', 'LINEA_TC_NU', 'HIPOTECARIO', 'DIAS_MORA', 'MICR_SALDO', 'MICR_LINEA', 'PEQ_SALDO', 'PEQ_LINEA', 'MED_SALDO', 'MED_LINEA'], ...data]);
            const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([['Identificacion', 'FEC_REPORTE', 'NORMAL', 'CPP', 'DEFICIENTE', 'DUDOSA', 'PERDIDA', 'ApellidoPaterno', 'PrimerNombre', 'ENTIDAD', 'TOTAL_CASTIGO', 'SALDO', 'LINEA'], ...data]);
            const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'RCC');
            XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'Resultados_RCC.xlsx');
        }

        // Esperar a que el DOM esté listo
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const exportButton = document.getElementById('exportButton');
            exportButton.addEventListener('click', exportToExcel);
        });
    </script>


    <script>

        // Obtener una referencia al campo de entrada del buscador
        const buscador = document.getElementById('buscador');

        // Obtener una referencia a las filas de la tabla
        const filas = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable2 tbody tr');

        // Agregar un evento de entrada al campo de búsqueda
        buscador.addEventListener('input', function () {
            const filtro = buscador.value.toLowerCase();

            filas.forEach(fila => {
                const celdas = fila.getElementsByTagName('td');
                let coincide = false;

                for (let i = 0; i < celdas.length; i++) {
                    const celda = celdas[i];
                    if (celda.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(filtro)) {
                        coincide = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                fila.style.display = coincide ? '' : 'none';
            });
        });

      

    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable2').DataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "pageLength": -1, // Muestra todos los registros en una sola página
                "lengthChange": false, // Deshabilita la opción de cambiar la cantidad de registros por página
                "language": {
                    "decimal": ",",
                    "thousands": ".",
                    "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron registros",
                    "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                    "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "search": "Buscar:",
                    "paginate": {
                        "first": "Primero",
                        "last": "Último",
                        "next": "Siguiente",
                        "previous": "Anterior"
                    },
                }
            });
        });

    </script>


}

y este es el index.cshtml.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace RCCSIC.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        // Definición de las variables de mensajes
        public string errorMessage { get; set; }
        public string successMessage { get; set; }
        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public List<Rccinfo> RCC = new List<Rccinfo>();

        public string Username { get; private set; }


        public IActionResult OnPostLogout()
        {
            // Elimina el nombre de usuario de la sesión para cerrar la sesión
            HttpContext.Session.Remove("UserName");
            return RedirectToPage("/Login");
        }


        public void OnGet()
        {
            // Verifica si el usuario está autenticado
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName") == null)
            {
                // Si el usuario no está autenticado, redirige a la página de login
                Response.Redirect("/Login");
            }
            else
            {
                // Si el usuario está autenticado, establece el nombre de usuario
                Username = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName");

                // Continúa con la lógica existente de tu método OnGet() aquí
                try
                {
                    // Cadena de conexión para el primer sistema
                    string connectionString = "Data Source=W10LIMJG\\STACIONLIMA;Initial Catalog=RCC_SICOBRA;Integrated Security=True";
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        string sql = @"
                            SELECT distinct b.nu_docu as DNI, b.nu_empr as NRO_EMPRESAS, c.fec_rep as FEC_REPORTE, 
                            str(convert(Decimal, b.nu_cali_norm))+'%' as NORMAL,
                            str(convert(Decimal, b.nu_cali_cpp))+ '%' as CPP,
                            str(convert(Decimal, b.nu_cali_defi))+'%' as DEFICIENTE,
                            str(convert(Decimal, b.nu_cali_dudo))+'%' as DUDOSA,
                            str(convert(Decimal, b.nu_cali_perd))+'%' as PERDIDA,
                            b.ap_pate as APELLIDO_PATERNO, b.ap_mate as APELLIDO_MATERNO, b.no_clie_prim as PRIMER_NOMBRE,
                            b.no_clie_segu as SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, d.nom_banco as ENTIDAD, c.total_castigo as TOTAL_CASTIGO, c.cons_saldo as SALDO, c.cons_linea as LINEA,
                            c.cons_linea_tc as LINEA_TC, c.cons_linea_tc_nu as LINEA_TC_NU, c.hipo_saldo as HIPOTECARIO, c.dias_mora as DIAS_MORA, c.micr_saldo as MICR_SALDO,
                            c.micr_linea as MICR_LINEA, c.pequ_saldo as PEQ_SALDO, c.pequ_linea as PEQ_LINEA,c.medi_saldo as MED_SALDO, c.medi_linea as MED_LINEA
                            FROM   dbo.t_rcc_clientemarzo24 b INNER JOIN dbo.t_rcc_detallemarzo24 c ON b.id_sbs  = c.cod_sbs_cli, dbo.bancos$ d, dbo.Documentos e
                            WHERE  b.nu_docu=e.DNI and c.cod_sbs_cli=b.id_sbs and c.fec_rep='20240229' and d.cod_banco=c.cod_emp
                            and fe_repo = '20240229'
                            ORDER BY dni
                            ";

                        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                        {
                            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                            {

                                //RCC = new List<Rccinfo>();
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    Rccinfo rccinfo = new Rccinfo();
                                    rccinfo.DNI = reader["DNI"].ToString();
                                    rccinfo.NRO_EMPRESAS = reader["NRO_EMPRESAS"].ToString();
                                    rccinfo.FEC_REPORTE = Convert.ToString(reader["FEC_REPORTE"]);
                                    rccinfo.NORMAL = reader["NORMAL"].ToString();
                                    rccinfo.CPP = reader["CPP"].ToString();
                                    rccinfo.DEFICIENTE = reader["DEFICIENTE"].ToString();
                                    rccinfo.DUDOSA = reader["DUDOSA"].ToString();
                                    rccinfo.PERDIDA = reader["PERDIDA"].ToString();
                                    rccinfo.APELLIDO_PATERNO = reader["APELLIDO_PATERNO"].ToString();
                                    rccinfo.APELLIDO_MATERNO = reader["APELLIDO_MATERNO"].ToString();
                                    rccinfo.PRIMER_NOMBRE = reader["PRIMER_NOMBRE"].ToString();
                                    rccinfo.SEGUNDO_NOMBRE = reader["SEGUNDO_NOMBRE"].ToString();
                                    rccinfo.ENTIDAD = reader["ENTIDAD"].ToString();
                                    rccinfo.TOTAL_CASTIGO = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["TOTAL_CASTIGO"]).ToString("0.00");
                                    rccinfo.SALDO = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["SALDO"]).ToString("0.00");
                                    rccinfo.LINEA = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["LINEA"]).ToString("0.00");
                                    rccinfo.LINEA_TC = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["LINEA_TC"]).ToString("0.00");
                                    rccinfo.LINEA_TC_NU = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["LINEA_TC_NU"]).ToString("0.00");
                                    rccinfo.HIPOTECARIO = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["HIPOTECARIO"]).ToString("0.00");
                                    rccinfo.DIAS_MORA = Convert.ToInt32(reader["DIAS_MORA"]).ToString("0.00");
                                    rccinfo.MICR_SALDO = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["MICR_SALDO"]).ToString("0.00");
                                    rccinfo.MICR_LINEA = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["MICR_LINEA"]).ToString("0.00");
                                    rccinfo.PEQ_SALDO = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["PEQ_SALDO"]).ToString("0.00");
                                    rccinfo.PEQ_LINEA = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["PEQ_LINEA"]).ToString("0.00");
                                    rccinfo.MED_SALDO = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["MED_SALDO"]).ToString("0.00");
                                    rccinfo.MED_LINEA = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["MED_LINEA"]).ToString("0.00");

                                    RCC.Add(rccinfo);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            // Aquí puedes mantener la lógica de tu método OnPost() existente

            
                if (Request.Form.ContainsKey("consultar"))
                {
                    string dniList = Request.Form["DNIs"];

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dniList))
                    {
                        errorMessage = "Debe ingresar al menos un DNI";
                        return;
                    }

                    string[] dnisArray = dniList.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    try
                    {
                        string connectionString = "Data Source=W10LIMJG\\STACIONLIMA;Initial Catalog=RCC_SICOBRA;Integrated Security=True";
                        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            string sql = "INSERT INTO Documentos (DNI) VALUES (@DNI);";
                            foreach (string dni in dnisArray)
                            {
                                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                                {
                                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DNI", dni.Trim());
                                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        successMessage = "Nuevos DNIs agregados correctamente";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        errorMessage = ex.Message;
                        return;
                    }

                    // Redirigir a la página principal
                    Response.Redirect("/Index");
                }
                else if (Request.Form.ContainsKey("limpiar"))
                {
                    // Lógica para limpiar la tabla "Documentos" en la base de datos
                    LimpiarDocumentos();
                    // Redirigir a la página principal después de limpiar los documentos
                    Response.Redirect("/Index");
                }
            }




            private void LimpiarDocumentos()
            {
                try
                {
                    string connectionString = "Data Source=W10LIMJG\\STACIONLIMA;Initial Catalog=RCC_SICOBRA;Integrated Security=True";
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        string sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE Documentos;";
                        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                        {
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }

                    // Puedes establecer mensajes o variables de estado para mostrar en tu interfaz si es necesario
                    // Por ejemplo:
                    TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Tabla Documentos truncada correctamente";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Puedes manejar errores aquí si lo deseas
                    TempData["ErrorMessage"] = ex.Message;
                }
            

        }

        public class Rccinfo
        {
            public string DNI { get; set; }
            public string NRO_EMPRESAS { get; set; }
            public string FEC_REPORTE { get; set; }
            public string NORMAL { get; set; }
            public string CPP { get; set; }
            public string DEFICIENTE { get; set; }
            public string DUDOSA { get; set; }
            public string PERDIDA { get; set; }
            public string APELLIDO_PATERNO { get; set; }
            public string APELLIDO_MATERNO { get; set; }
            public string PRIMER_NOMBRE { get; set; }
            public string SEGUNDO_NOMBRE { get; set; }
            public string ENTIDAD { get; set; }
            public string TOTAL_CASTIGO { get; set; }
            public string SALDO { get; set; }
            public string LINEA { get; set; }
            public string LINEA_TC { get; set; }
            public string LINEA_TC_NU { get; set; }
            public string HIPOTECARIO { get; set; }
            public string DIAS_MORA { get; set; }
            public string MICR_SALDO { get; set; }
            public string MICR_LINEA { get; set; }
            public string PEQ_SALDO { get; set; }
            public string PEQ_LINEA { get; set; }
            public string MED_SALDO { get; set; }
            public string MED_LINEA { get; set; }
        }
    }
}

todo este codigo es lo que concidero que debemos revisar, he intentado quitar la paginacion y busqueda pero permacenece el problema,
he intentado quitar cualquier efecto a la tabla y el problema permacece, que podria ser?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Solo para descartar, probaste ese query dentro de sql y trae todos los registros que vos decis?

esto "TRUNCATE TABLE Documentos" no suena a una buena idea.. porque querrias destrozar una tabla productiva de esa forma?

Quita el script del Datatable para testear si el problema está ahí o en el servidor

Parece mucho código, ¿es realmente necesario? ¿qué tal un [mcve]?

Estás quemando fechas de busqueda dentro de tu tabla, es esto correcto? De igual forma, esto nunca debería de quedar "quemado dentro del codigo". Podría empezar revisando eso, sino, depurar el código dentro del while para verificar, que por algún motivo no se esté cayendo el método, esto con algún formato de campo que no coincida con los tipos de datos que definiste.
